# PIC18F13K50 Has two or one Half Bridge control?

Tags: pic, microchip

Since the PIC18F13K50 has one ECCP, and it can operate in single, full and half bridge, I dont undestand if it can drive 2 half bridges at the same time, or just one...it appears to be just one though...

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right: when you look at the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41350E.pdf), page 121, you can see the output configurations. In table 14-2 you can then see that the PIC18F13K50 can only drive a single half-bridge. (This is further confirmed in part 14.4.1 on page 124)

Comment: Damn...I wanted 2...do you know why someone will want just one half-bridge, inverted like this one? The datasheet says push-pull control, but I dont see where I will use it..

Comment: The half-bridge is interesting for switched-mode power supplies, where it used as synchronous rectifier. But this can be useful for a motor driver too, as long as you only have a single direction ([an example](http://www.4qd.co.uk/fea/half.html)).

Comment: But I just need to activate one MOSFET right? Why the half bridge?

Comment: One FET delivers current to the motor, the other one acts as [freewheeling diode[(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) (this is the "synchronous rectifier" part - you don't need an additional diode). But if you want to skip the second FET, you can replace it with a diode.

Comment: Every FET comes with a diode...it's part of the fabrication process...turning it on just makes the thermal managing better, since the voltage drop on them is a lot smaller...

Comment: The freewheeling diode has nothing to do with the one in the FET. It is needed because otherwise the voltage spikes generated by the motor when turning the lower FET in the half-bridge off will kill it.

Comment: Yep...and that's what the internal diodes do as well..but generaly they are bad to use, because they cant stand much current...here is a good article about it: http://robots.freehostia.com/SpeedControl/SpeedControllersBody.html